Divergent sum of two series appears to converge by alternating series test
I have been given the following sum:
$$
\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} a_n,  a_n = \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}+\frac{1}{n}
$$
The terms seem to be alternating.
Observe that $\left|\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}\right| > \frac{1}{n}$ for all $n\ge1$.
$$
\implies sign({a_n}) = sign\left(\frac{(-1)^n}{sqrt(n)}\right)
$$
Similarly, the same goes for $a_{n+1}$. Therefore:
$$
sign(a_n)*sign(a_{n+1}) = \frac{\left|\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{\sqrt{n+1}}\right|}{\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{\sqrt{n+1}}} * \frac{\left|\frac{(-1)^{n}}{\sqrt{n}}\right|}{\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}} = -1 < 0
$$
$a_n$ also seems to converge to 0 and decreasing - all conditions for the alternating series test seem to be fulfilled, but I can show that the series must diverge.
This is for school and I am supposed to explain why this result is not in conflict with the test for alternating series. I understand why it diverges, but I am at a loss as to why the test for alternating series seems to suggest otherwise.

Have you written out the $a_n$?  Certainly don't appear to be decreasing...here are the first $100$ terms.

"decreasing" means $|a_n|>|a_{n+1}|$ for all $n$ (or at least, for all sufficiently large $n$).  I showed you the first $100$ values.  Not decreasing.

Ah, thanks. I did indeed not bother writing it out, and made a mistake when comparing $|a_n|$ to $|a_{n+1}|$. Thanks.

Did you try to sum two consecutive (pairs) to get rid of the alteration of the sign? This will create a new sum with positive terms only which might be easier to evaluate.

The terms are of the form $(-1)^nb_n,$ where $$b_n={1\over \sqrt{n}}+{(-1)^n\over n}$$ The sequence  $b_n$ is positive for $n\ge 2$ but it is not decreasing because $b_{2n-1}< b_{2n}.$
